# How to use 'when' keyword in Angular

Tags: angular

I've noticed a `when` keyword in Angular Material's Tree, but i could not find the documentation for it. I suspect it will render the templet only if the condition is truthy, but I would like more information on it's usage if anyone can provide.

Relevant code:
`<mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a property of the [`MatTreeNodeDef`](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/api#MatTreeNodeDef) directive of Angular Material Tree. In the documentation link, you can find it in the table, defined as `matTreeNodeDefWhen` and as per the documentation, it is -

> Function that should return true if this node template should be used
>   for the provided node data and index. If left undefined, this node
>   will be considered the default node template to use when no other when
>   functions return true for the data. For every node, there must be at
>   least one when function that passes or an undefined to default.

Comment: It's funny that I've missed that. I've read the api documentation twice. So I guess it's not part of a 'core' structural directive (like *ngTemplateOutlet for ex) but rather a part of the TreeNode implementation.

Comment: That's right. Sometimes, shorthanded properties are easy to miss and be confused with the core implementation. If it was being used as `matTreeNodeDefWhen`, I don't think there would have been a confusion in the first place